# How can I change value according to icon(with it's class) that was clicked in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I just began to learn Vue.js and need some little help)
I have a table with three icons. When I click one of these icons, I need some info from json to be displayed, and this info is different for all these 3 icons.
I have a value "isActive", and it works fine when I switch this value manually (1,2,3) in App.vue file. 
But I need this value to be changed dynamically according to the icon that was clicked:

```
'fas fa-check' => isActive=1

'fas fa-times' => isActive=2

'fas fa-minus' => isActive=3
```

How can I change '**isActive**' value from '**MainTable.vue**' file according to icon that was clicked?

````
App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Table</h1> 
    <MainPage v-bind:mainPageInfo="mainPageInfo" v-on:main-handle="handler(loadGeneralQuestInfo, loadFinishedQuestleafs)" />      

    <div>   
    <ul v-bind:key="data.id" v-for="data in generalQuestInfo">
      <li v-if="data.alias == 'BN' && isActive == 1">
      Build ID: {{data.globalId}} Platform: {{data.platform}} Quest Name: {{data.alias}}  Status: {{data.pathway.status}} Path Name: {{data.pathway.name}}</li>
      <li v-else-if="data.alias == 'SAM' && isActive == 2">Build ID: {{data.globalId}} Platform: {{data.platform}} Quest Name: {{data.alias}}  Status: {{data.pathway.status}} Path Name: {{data.pathway.name}}</li>
      <li v-else-if="isActive == 3">NO INFO</li>
      </ul>    

    </div>  
      </div>
    </template>

    export default {
      name: 'app',
      components: {
        MainPage   
      },

      data(){
      return {
        mainPageInfo: [],
          generalQuestInfo: [],
          finishedQuestleafs: [],
        isActive: 2
      }
    }



  MainTable.vue 

       <template>
            <div>
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                      <th v-bind:key="data.id" v-for="data in mainPageInfo">{{data.alias}}</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>        
                        <td v-bind:key="data.id" v-for="data in mainPageInfo">          
                            <i v-on:click="$emit('main-handle')" v-bind:class="data.status == 'SUCCESS' ? 'fas fa-check': 
                                data.status == 'CRASH' ? 'fas fa-times' : 
                                'fas fa-minus'"></i>            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </template>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the click handler you can pass the status to `$emit`:

```html
<i v-on:click="$emit('main-handle', data.status)" ...>
```

In the listener for the `main-handle` event this will be accessible as `$event`:

```html
<MainPage v-on:main-handle="handler(loadGeneralQuestInfo, loadFinishedQuestleafs, $event)" ...>
```

In the method `handler` you can then set `isActive` based on the status.

There are various other ways you might do this, such as using 3 separate events.